# Looking for a Z80 simulator/emulator for Linux

Tags: emulation, z80, simulator

I've seen simulators for the 8085 (i.e., [sim8085](http://www.homesoft.gen.tr/sim8085)) but not the Zilog Z80.

Is there a similar sort of editor/assembler/compiler/debugger simulator for the Z80?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for here. Do you want a simulator for a specific Z80 based system (i.e., like the Model I) or a library that simulates a Z80 that can be used as the basis for something else? It's also unclear why you mention the TRS-80 Model I and 4.

Comment: By the way, when clarifying a question you should [edit](http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/posts/441/edit) the question to update it instead of hiding details in the comments.

Comment: Ok, it appears that you are looking for a software emulation of a generic turnkey Z80 based system (i.e., with some basic I/O, ROM routines, and RAM) with a simulated classic editor/assembler/debugger interface. You may want to check the MAME/MESS project to see if someone has ported a specific single-board Z80 board to MAME.

Comment: Also, mashing "Z80 simulator" into a web search yields interesting results.

Comment: seems top me you'd be better off combining an IDE emulator and assembler, than trying to find a single-purpose tool that will probably do three things badly

Comment: I don't think this comment deserves an answer, but [this link](http://www.z80.info/z80sdt.htm) has some information that, while a bit dated, may end up being useful

Answer (score 8):

You may have more success if looking for CP/M emulators for Linux, as CP/M ran in a 8080/Z80 environment. The very own CP/M environment can be your development environment. One could be "YAZE-AG - Yet Another Z80 Emulator"
http://www.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/users/ag/yaze-ag/

But if you are looking for something more.... "visual", I'd suggest to take a look at z80pack.
http://www.autometer.de/unix4fun/z80pack/

Both run in Windows and UNIX systems.

*(Side note: I just love those front panels :) )*

Comment: Note that there is several kinds of CP/M.  You need the CP/M-80 variant.

Answer (score 7):

I've been using [Z80Pack](http://www.autometer.de/unix4fun/z80pack) recently on a project, and it works pretty well. (I'm working on a bank-switcher and SD ROM loader for the RC2014 project.)

Comment: What is "SD ROM loader"? An SD card-based system that emulates a ROM?

Comment: Voted up because Z80Pack has a comprehensive and well organized list of software _and manuals_ all together on one page.

Answer (score 4):

**[Z80.info](http://www.z80.info/z80emu.htm)** has a HUGE list of emulators for many platforms. Some links may be broken, though - because the website was moved or does not exist any more. Either way, googling with the name of the emulator itself will solve the problem.

I think you should favorite this page (I did!). It has useful information regarding the subject.

### Suggestions

I like [**Toledo**](http://nanochess.org/emulator.html) - a CP/M emulator; it considers the Intel 8080, not the Z80. But I like it, and it won the [IOCCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Obfuscated_C_Code_Contest)! You will need to compile it and maybe adjust something. But not much of what you want (simulates the system not the processor).

There is also [ZIM](http://www.natmac.net/zim/) which can be used in a Java Virtual Machine (JVM). It speeds the use of the tool, because it just needs the JVM installed, not requiring compiling or installation of other tools (Java is usually used by multiple applications for your PC).

ZIM also works within the browser if the Java Web Start plugin is available to your browser (Firefox and Internet Explorer; Chrome doesn't support Java any more). I think it's very handy! It will work on a wide variety of modern OSes and within the browser! :P

ZIM ***should be*** something along *SIM8085*. So I hope it helped!

Comment: Can you clarify what "fastens the use" means? Your first sentence describes exactly why link-heavy answers are doomed to be outdated.

Comment: I'm sorry about the 'fastens'. I got cough into something similar to a false cognate - I don't really know this concept in english. I'm already editing to be clearer. But about the first sentence: it clearly does not do any bad having Z80.info as I selected the two suggestions I could think of were the best and could help Mr. Pittel. And I provided the website of the tools - not some dead link. Also, Z80.info is one of the best sites that have cataloged information on the subject. Not having it would be a sin and wrong with their effort. Remember: links aren't the enemy; they are the internet.

Answer (score 4):

I use z80asm to assemble/compile, and z80dasm to dissasemble to source. Both are usually found in your package manager.
I can load compiled code into the fuse emulator (spectrum) and run it succesfully.

Comment: Confirming that this is a pretty good option for quick and easy Z80 development. Combined with appmake from the [z88dk](http://www.z88dk.org/forum/ "z88dk") package, you can build ready-to-go emulator images in one step

Answer (score 2):

Although commercial, [IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/) is an outstanding (dynamic) disassembler and debugger for the Z80.

Comment: That IDA can debug z80 is good information! How does it run the code though? What emulators does it support? Can you link to something on their site that supports this (I can't find anything!), or walk through a brief demonstration? It might be useful to expand upon this in your answer.

Comment: Just used it as disassember, not as a debugger via emulator :(